Dockerized Kong introspection endpoint problem
I am trying to create docker environment via following this tutorial here
However, in the last step I am receiving following error even though I did everything as mentioned:
Request:
curl "http://${HOST_IP}:8000/mock-postman"  -H "Accept: application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TKN"
Response:
accessing introspection endpoint (http://192.168.0.46:8180/realms/experimental/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect) failed: timeout
Why might I receive such an error? Any ideas?
I have tried redoing every step to see if I missed something but couldn't find anything.
Also, without a bearer token gateway acts as expected.
Request:
 curl "http://${HOST_IP}:8000/mock-postman"-H "Accept:application/json"-I

Response:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Jun 2024 18:22:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="experimental",error="no Authorization header found"
X-Kong-Response-Latency: 1
Server: kong/2.8.3

Btw, my docker-compose.yml is as following no different than in the tutorial:
version: '3.4'

networks: 
  kong-net:
    driver: bridge
  keycloak-net:

volumes:
  kong-datastore:
  keycloak-datastore:

services:
  kong-db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    volumes:
      - kong-datastore:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:       api-gw
      POSTGRES_USER:     kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong

  kong:
    build:
      context: ./      
    image: kong-oidc:latest
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # Listener
      - "8001:8001" # Admin API
      - "8443:8443" # Listener  (SSL)
      - "8444:8444" # Admin API (SSL)
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE:         postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST:          kong-db
      KONG_PG_PORT:          5432
      KONG_PG_DATABASE:      api-gw
      KONG_PG_USER:          kong
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD:      kong
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG:  /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG:  /dev/stderr
      KONG_PROXY_LISTEN:     0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN:     0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      KONG_PLUGINS:          bundled,oidc
      KONG_LOG_LEVEL:        debug

  konga:
    image: pantsel/konga:0.14.9
    depends_on:
      - kong
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - "1337:1337" # konga
    environment:
      DB_ADAPTER: postgres
      DB_HOST: kong-db
      DB_PORT: '5432'
      DB_USER: kong
      DB_PASSWORD: kong
      DB_DATABASE: api-gw
      NODE_ENV: development

  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes: 
      - keycloak-datastore:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - keycloak-net
    ports:
      - "25432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:       keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER:     keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db
    command: start-dev
    networks:
      - keycloak-net
    ports:
      - "8180:8080"
    environment:
      KC_DB:       postgres
      KC_DB_URL:   jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-db/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN:           admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD:  admin
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: 1

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    depends_on:
      - kong
    container_name: prometheus
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command: "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus"
    ports: 
      - 9090:9090

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    container_name: grafana
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

According to kong logs there is no error:
2024/06/05 12:02:59 [debug] 1108#0: *75515 [lua] openidc.lua:392: openidc_call_token_endpoint(): request body for introspection endpoint call: token=<my_token>&client_secret=<my_client_secret>&client_id=kong
2024/06/05 12:02:59 [debug] 1108#0: *75515 [lua] openidc.lua:354: openidc_configure_proxy(): openidc_configure_proxy : don't use http proxy
2024/06/05 12:03:04 [debug] 1118#0: *75855 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:09 [debug] 1126#0: *76216 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:14 [debug] 1122#0: *76577 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:19 [debug] 1110#0: *76938 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:24 [debug] 1117#0: *77299 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:29 [debug] 1109#0: *77659 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:34 [debug] 1120#0: *78021 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:39 [debug] 1117#0: *78382 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:44 [debug] 1121#0: *78742 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:49 [debug] 1127#0: *79103 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:54 [debug] 1115#0: *79464 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:59 [debug] 1116#0: *79825 [lua] init.lua:288: [cluster_events] polling events from: 1717588494.292
2024/06/05 12:03:59 [error] 1108#0: *75515 [lua] openidc.lua:405: openidc_call_token_endpoint(): accessing introspection endpoint (http://192.168.0.18:8180/realms/experimental/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect) failed: timeout, client: 192.168.0.18, server: kong, request: "GET /mock-postman HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.18:8000"
192.168.0.18 - - [05/Jun/2024:12:03:59 +0000] "GET /mock-postman HTTP/1.1" 401 148 "-" "curl/8.5.0"
2024/06/05 12:03:59 [info] 1108#0: *75515 client 192.168.0.18 closed keepalive connection
enter code here


What's Kong error log looks like? I think the error log will give you more clue on why the error happened.

@Ponsakorn30214 added kong logs to the question. According to logs I can't see any error

Even though I couldn't get an answer from this community, I managed to solve my problem and written a medium article to answer this question:
https://medium.com/@cigtekinadnan/what-is-api-gateway-and-how-to-use-it-a880cc6318ee
It seems there were some missing steps in the tutorial which I was following, so I fixed that.
